# Possible solutions for Linux mdadm "raid5" over devices with different sizes?

Tags: linux, lvm, mdadm

I have server with 5 disks of 4TB, 2 with 8TB, and 1 10TB.

I'd like to bundle them all together into Raid5/Raid6.

As far as I understand one cannot do it nicely with disks of varying sizes.

But I figured I could partition each disk into partitions of 2TB each, and then make separate raid5 devices over these partitions, making sure that i never use more than one partition from single disk for single raid device, and then I can put raid0 (or lvm) over all generated devices.

Am I overthinking it, or is it a viable solution?

Comment: Is the first sentence supposed to say TB rather than GB? Assuming that is the case, why 2TB rather than 4TB (which would appear to be the largest size all drives can accommodate)?

Comment: 1. Fixed GB/TB typo
2. I want to use multiple partitions per disk, and 10TB is not divisible by 4, but is by 2.

Comment: It is viable and works great for me! It has handled online reshaping and disk failures without any issues. I use btrfs in single profile to composite the raid5s into a single partition. Be careful to choose a partition size slightly smaller than 1TB or 2TB and correctly aligned - I use 1000190509056 bytes, which fits a variety of ages of disk. Can probably *2 this for 2TB.